# kafka message sent from one machine to another

Tags: apache-kafka

I have started this tutorial https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart, It works fine in case of local host

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

but when I want to sent text on another machine like
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server 10.22.241.59:9092

this gives me below error

[image]

```
WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error connecting to node test-3-workernode:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

how can I send to message other machine? why it is not connecting?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. But which part of that error message is unclear?

Comment: @OlafKock  bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server 10.22.241.59:9092 this command gives me error. I mean when I write something to send it gives me error. That it is not connecting with another machine

Comment: Can you share any kafka properties/config? Is Kafka bootstrap server process is started/installed at that machine?

Comment: yes I have followed the tutorial bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties and bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties both running then run command  bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 and write something it appears when i check bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic quickstart-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Comment: @suraj_fale but I want to sent text to another machine from this machine and instead of local host when I used another IP it gives me error

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by sending text to another machine. You send/publish message to Kafka broker. To do that Kafka broker has to be installed on machine with that IP. If Kafka broker is already up and running on 10.22.241.59 here. Try publishing message via FQDN(hostname) instead of IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the broker such that it tells the client where to connect to it. This is done using the `advertised.listeners` setting. Without it the broker looks like it is defaulting to the hostname of the machine, which you client is not able to resolve.
Whilst your client uses the IP address that you've specified for the *initial* connection, it uses the host details that the *broker* provides for subsequent connections.

You can learn more about this here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: ok I will try and get back to you if I will have another issue